# How can I resolve "Exception caught by gesture RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0"

Tags: json, flutter, dart

```
           String chatRoomId(String peter, String goodone) {
   if (goodone[0].toLowerCase().codeUnits[0] >
       peter.toLowerCase().codeUnits[0]) {
     return "$goodone$peter";
   } else {
     return "$peter$goodone";
   }
 }

      userMap!=null?ListTile(
          onTap: (){
            String roomId = chatRoomId(_auth.currentUser!.displayName!,
                 userMap!['name']);
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => ChatRoom(
                  chatRoomId: roomId,
                  userMap: userMap!,
                ),
              )
            );
          },
            title: Text(userMap!['name'],style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),),
            subtitle: Text(userMap!['email']),
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_box),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.chat),
          ):Container()
```

I think the problem is in this part of the code cuz I can't go on the ChatRoom screen when I want to go on The Chat Room screen or another this error pop up :
"Exception caught by gesture
The following RangeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0"

```
class ChatRoom extends StatelessWidget {

final Map<String,dynamic> userMap;
final String chatRoomId;

ChatRoom({required this.chatRoomId, required this.userMap});

final TextEditingController _message = TextEditingController();
final FirebaseFirestore _firestore =FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

If somoene can help I will be really greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String peter` or `String goodone` might be empty strings
you are trying to access a codeUnit position

```
 if (goodone[0].toLowerCase().codeUnits[0] >
       peter.toLowerCase().codeUnits[0])
```

and they might be empty string

Comment: I'm really dumb this two accounts wasn't in my database sorry